# How to select view in Oracle from another connection(other user)?

Tags: database, oracle, select

I want to select a view from my sys user, but with other connection. I need to select view DBA_USERS. Is there any way of doing so? I am new in Oracle, so maybe it is silly question, but still, I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `select * from SYS.DBA_USERS;` ? (it has been a long time since I used Oracle)
(The user you are actually connecting from may not have the privileges to read the table.)
Also you could try `select * from ALL_USERS;`

Comment: Can't you use all_users instead of dba_users?

Comment: To grant access (from memory) you would need to log in as SYS and type 'GRANT SELECT ON DBA_USERS TO yourotherloginname;